# Huge number of errors in Texstudio on Ubuntu, none in Windows

Tags: errors

If I try to compile the following in Texstudio on Linux:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg}
\setlength{\voffset}{-1in}
\setlength{\footskip}{.5in}
\setlength{\textheight}{9in}
\setlength{\marginparsep}{0in}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{1in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{.5in}
\setlength{\hoffset}{0in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{5in}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition} 
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathpzc}{OT1}{pzc}{m}{it}
\sectionfont{\fontsize{12}{15}\selectfont}
\title{title}
\author{me}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

I get a huge number of errors. However, if I try to compile the same thing in Texstudio on windows, it works fine. Any ideas?

Comment: First guess: missing packages. But can't help without further informations

Comment: show the error log from TeX, just saying "huge number of errors" doesn't allow anyone to help you

Comment: Thank you for posting a working example! At the same time, much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose.

Answer (score 3):

I added an `a` as document content...

First error

```
! Package subcaption Error: This package can't be used in cooperation
(subcaption)                with the subfig package.

See the subcaption package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.60   \endinput}{}
                   %
?
```

What is this telling you? Just what it says: you cannot use **subcaption** with **subfig**. So, one or other of those packages needs to go. Note that this is as true on Windows as on Linux or anything else. The OS is irrelevant. (Though your editor might hide errors from you, I guess. If so, better get a new editor.)

The number of errors is usually immaterial. The first is typically the one which matters. Only once that is fixed can you tell if there are additional, distinct errors or just fall out from the first one.

Removing **subfig**, the code compiles without error.

However **times** is obsolete and the next package will overwrite it anyhow, so let's drop that.

We don't need to specify graphics extensions with current **graphicx**. Better let the package figure it out as it is more portable and flexible.

Finally, it is much better to use a package such as **geometry** rather than trying to set page dimensions manually because **geometry** will make sure everything works out and calculate unspecified dimensions appropriately. See the documentation for details of more intuitive ways to specify the document layout.

Anyway, that might give you something like this

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{%
  footskip=.5in,
  textheight=9in,
  textwidth=5in,
  marginparsep=0pt,
  marginparwidth=1in,
  left=1.5in,
}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathpzc}{OT1}{pzc}{m}{it}
\sectionfont{\fontsize{12}{15}\selectfont}
\title{title}
\author{me}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
a
\end{document}
```